# What does “be (totally) on” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Today I come across the headline、“Meek and Nicki are still totally on” followed by sub-headline, “Just stop asking when they're getting engaged.” in the Scene site.

Does “A and B are on” mean A and B have a very close relationship? Is it a common phrase?

Comment: "On" has easily a dozen different slang meanings, but in general it means "hot".

Comment: The writer is evidently attempting to emulate the speech of American adolescent females of limited denotative vocabulary, (Opinion of one who successfully parented one; for a whole year she conversed with four words: God, like, man, and dude...) I would infer that Meek and Nicki continue their intense amatory affiliation.

Comment: I agree with Rob_Ster that the implication of the statement is that the relationship (and its seriousness) are still on (on track, ongoing, on the move, hitting on all fours) rather than being off. The very generic-sounding "It's on!" in U.S. slang means "It's happening," "It's going to occur," "It's serious now," "The battle is about to begin," etc.

Comment: It needs to be understood that "totally on" is different from just "on".  The latter might simply mean that they haven't cancelled their date for tonight, but "totally on" means that they are, like, all over each other, ya know?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this particular use of "being on", but it appears to me to be a small extension of a use that is familiar to me:

> Are we still on for 3:00?

Which is informal and abbreviated of:

> Are we still planning to `X` at 3:00?

Where `X` is most likely some kind of meeting, which in turn is most likely an informal meal. The question is most likely being asked because an obligation may preempt `X`.

This usage is in reference to a specific social event, while the headline in question appears to refer to an ongoing social relationship. Nevertheless, it feels natural to me that "John and Jane are still on" indicates that doubts regarding the continuation of some relationship between John and Jane have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The term "totally on" is lingo commonly used by magazines such as Seventeen, Redbook, or Tiger beat. It means that the two people are still dating, or still "an item". In this case it is referring to rappers Meek Mill and Nicki Minaj. Meek and Nicki are still dating now.